# Creditworthiness indicator for copula one-factor model

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, copula, credit-risk, credit-ratings

In this [paper](http://www.r2-financial.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/RMFI-5-3_p252-272.pdf-Adobe-Acrobat-Standard.pdf) in equation 15 on page 261 dealing with one factor copula model, one is using creditworthiness indicator as one of a variables. It is defined as

\begin{equation}
Y_c = \sqrt{\rho_c} Z + \sqrt{1-\rho_c} \epsilon_c
\end{equation}
where Z is a systematic factor influencing default an it is standard normal distributed. Can one make it clearer and let me know what Z should be? Can we take credit spread (and implicitly assume spread is normally distributed?)

Comment: In what paper did you find this?

Comment: http://www.r2-financial.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/RMFI-5-3_p252-272.pdf-Adobe-Acrobat-Standard.pdf

Comment: page 261, equation 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this [paper](http://www.gravitascapital.com/Research/Risk/Applying%20Copula%20Function%20to%20Risk%20Management.pdf) might be helpful